# For loop only writes one object into a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate over a JSON file and write specific key values to a new JSON file:

```
def get_rubrik_failed_archives_main():
    with open("get_failed_archives.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for archive_data in json_data["data"]:
        dictionary = {
            "objectName": archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"],
            "time": archive_data["latestEvent"]["time"],
            "eventType": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventType"],
            "eventStatus": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventStatus"]
            }
        with open("rubrik_failed_archives.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(dictionary, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to write multiple objects into the JSON file, as I only get one object:

```
    {
    "eventStatus": "Failure",
    "eventType": "Archive",
    "objectName": "Template",
    "time": "2022-08-21T16:09:31.863Z"
    }
```

How do I write a for loop so that all of the needed key values get written into the new JSON file?

Comment: you know what file mode "w" does, right? BTW if you wtire your json-s as you are trying to write, you will NOT get a valid json data file

Comment: It appears you need the ‘append’ mode (`'a'`) rather than the ‘write’ mode; which truncates (deletes contents) with each access.

Comment: Append mode will *not* produce valid JSON though, just several concatenated JSON files

Comment: What would produce a valid JSON?

Comment: Do you want all of the `json_data["data"]` content written to a new JSON file? If so then why the loop and not just write that to a new file?

Comment: generate the json first as a python list of dict object, and then save that outside of your for loop

Comment: Instead of writing a dictionary at each step, have you tried to add the dictionary into a bigger dictionary, then dump it once after the loop ends?

Comment: also note that if you skip the indent, and write each dict object on a new line in the file, you're basically creating an [NDJSON](http://ndjson.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that new data cannot be updated in dictionary.

So, The answer I came up with is `json_data.update(dictionary)`to add to the for loop.

```
def get_rubrik_failed_archives_main():
    with open("get_failed_archives.json") as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for archive_data in json_data["data"]:
        dictionary = {
            "objectName": archive_data["latestEvent"]["objectName"],
            "time": archive_data["latestEvent"]["time"],
            "eventType": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventType"],
            "eventStatus": archive_data["latestEvent"]["eventStatus"]
            }
        json_data.update(dictionary)
        with open("rubrik_failed_archives.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(dictionary, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

I don't know if it will be solved because I can't check it, but I hope it helps you.